# Convert data from an excel file into a python dictionary

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I'm trying to convert data from an excel file to a python dictionary. My excel file has has two columns and many rows.

```
Name    Age
Steve   11
Mike    10
John    11
```

How do I go about adding this into a dictionary with Age as the key and name as the value? Also, if many names have the same age, they should all be in an array. For example:

```
{'11':['Steve','John'],'10':['Mike']}
```

What I've written so far:

```
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('demo.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

#print sheet.cell(row=2, column=2).value


age_and_names = {}

for i in range(1,11):

    age = sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value
    name = sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value  

#Problem seems to be in this general area
    if not age in age_and_names:
        age_and_names[age]=[]

        age_and_names[age].append(name)    

print age_and_names
```

What should I have done for the desired output? I'm very new to python. All help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a simple indentation error and your code is incorrect

```
#Problem seems to be in this general area
    if not age in age_and_names:
        age_and_names[age]=[]
        age_and_names[age].append(name)
```

should be

```
#Problem seems to be in this general area
    if not age in age_and_names:
        age_and_names[age]=[]

    age_and_names[age].append(name)
```

Otherwise you destroy previous data from `age_and_names[age]`.

You should consider using `collections.defaultdict` instead to avoid testing if key exists:

Declare like this

```
from collections import defaultdict

age_and_names = defaultdict(list)
```

Use like this:

```
age_and_names[12].append("Mike")
```

If the dict has no key `12`, it will invoke the `list` method and will create an empty list for you. No need to test if key exists in the first place.

Comment: This code works, but it has weird characters all around the keys and values:
`{1L: [u'dmvyc'], 4L: [u'aorbe', u'ebphb', u'nprrj'], 5L: [u'fgyfg'], 6L: [u'ralno'], 7L: [u'zaysd', u'wmklg', u'gsdhy', u'cqiki']}`

Comment: that's the representation of the dict, don't worry if you print each element you won't get that. (u is for unicode and L is for long integer)

Comment: No even if I print `print age_and_names[6]` it prints `[u'ralno']`

Comment: @Di437 That's because you are printing the list. If you want just an element in the list you have to index inside the list: `print age_and_names[6][0]` Also, you should probably be using Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

For this case, use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead of a plain dictionary `{}`); `collections.defaultdict` takes a factory function that is used to construct values for new keys. Use `list` to construct an empty list for each key:

```
import collections
age_and_names = collections.defaultdict(list)

...
     age_and_names[age].append(name)
```

No `if`s are needed.